# Adding data to an entity through a view controller

Tags: ios, core-data, entity

I have a case where I should insert object into an entity via `UIViewController`. I have designed my database model (Entity and attributes). I'm adding the entity through a `UIViewController`. What am I supposed to add in the `didFinishLaunchingwithOptions` method in appDelegate.m?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch   
    return YES;
}
```

And for the `TUTViewController` (My own view controller - `UIViewController`) I have used the below code for inserting object.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSString *stripped1 = [response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];
    NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[stripped1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
    NSMutableArray *contentArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[rows count]]; 
    NSMutableArray *contentArray1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[rows count]];

    NSArray *components;
    NSLog(@"count:%d",[rows count]);

    for (int i=0;i<[rows count]; i++) {

       if(i == 0 || [[rows objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@""]){
          continue;
       }

       components = [[rows objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
       id x = [components objectAtIndex:0] ;
       id y = [components objectAtIndex:1];
       id z = [components objectAtIndex:2];

       [contentArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x,@"X",y,@"Y", nil]];
       [contentArray1 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x,@"X",z,@"Y", nil]];

       [newManagedObject setValue:[x] forKey:@"timeStamp"];
       [newManagedObject setValue:[y] forKey:@"beat"];
       [newManagedObject setValue:[z] forKey:@"rate"];

       // Save the context.
       NSError *error = nil;
       if (![context save:&error]) {

           NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
           abort();

           NSLog(@"Contents of Uterus Contraction: %@",contentArray);
           NSLog(@"Contents of Heart Beat: %@",contentArray1);
       }    
    }
}
```

Is there anything that I'm missing? I'm ending up with the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not
>   locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'FetalData''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set up the Core Data Stack or a `UIManagedDocument` object?

If you didn't set up the Managed Object Model this could be the problem. It means you're probably not loading Managed Object Model that defines `FetalData` entity. See [insertnewobjectforentityforname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780929/insertnewobjectforentityforname) for further info.

I really suggest to create an empty project and let Xcode to create Core Data stuff for you. In this manner you can see how the code works.

**Some Notes**

Why do you use a `NSFetchResultsController`?

Move the `save` call at the end of your method. In this manner you avoid multiple round trips to the disk.

If you want to start using Core Data, I suggest you [core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started).

Hope it helps.