# +entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Ditloide' in a second view

Tags: core-data, entity, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I try to explain my problem.

I have a first view in which I have some buttons. Pressing a button the app open a tableview. I have those files in my project:

- AppDelegate.h/m
- viewcontroller.h/m to control the first view
- Entity1TableViewController.h/m to control the tableview opened by that
  button in 1st view
- an .xcdatamodel

so, until I'm in the tableview all is right. I putted this

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
 NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Ditloide" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

and when I tab on the button I receive the error:

```
+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Ditloide' in a second view
```

I read other posts in which I found something like this:

```
MainViewController *controller = (MainViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

to put in the rootcontroller. but in my case, where can I put this? I have to create a new controller? if yes, I cant insert the

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method.

So, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Can you add the code where you create your `managedObjectContext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure I understand your question.

The error is due to the fact you didn't set up the MOC correctly. See [insertNewObjectForEntityForName:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780929/insertnewobjectforentityforname) for further details.

The question is: did you set up the core data stack correctly? Could you share some code?

Then, about the code you have seen, it has the goal to inject the context wherever it is needed. For example, suppose you have a controller, called `YourController`, that needs the context. You can create a property in `YourController` like the following:

```
//.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext* context; // or strong if you ARC

//.m
@synthesize context;
```

Then, from a different element, for example the app delegate (if you have set up the core data stack there), you could just create `YourController` and inject it.

```
YourController* yourCtr = // alloc-init
yourCtr.context = [self managedObjectContext];
```

Finally, what do you mean with *if yes, I cant insert the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method*?